# Использование jQuery toggle в галерее

Tags: jquery

В html есть код:

```
<div id="switchGal">
    <p>Показать/Скрыть галерею</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="big">
        <img src="images/gal/start.jpg" alt="Старт" />
    </div>
    <div id="small">
        <a href="images/gal/1.jpg">
            <img src="images/gal/1_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 1" />
        </a>
        <a href="images/gal/2.jpg">
            <img src="images/gal/2_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 2" />
        </a>
        <a href="images/gal/3.jpg">
            <img src="images/gal/3_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 3" />
        </a>
        <a href="images/gal/4.jpg">
            <img src="images/gal/4_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 4" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот скрипт, который должен скрывать галерею и показывать:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#small a').click(function (eventOject) {
        $('#big img').hide().attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
        $('#big img').load(function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(1000);
        });
        return false;
    }); // конец click
    $('#switchGal').toggle(function () {
        $('#gallery').fadeToggle(2000);
    },
    function () {
        $('#gallery').fadeToggle(2000);
    });
}); //конец ready
```

В css блок gallery скрыл изначально.

Проблема в том, что скрывается сам текст "Показать/Скрыть галерею", а должна показывается при первом щелчке галерея, а при втором скрывается. Не знаю, в чём ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: отформатируйте код

Comment: [version deprecated: 1.8, removed: 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) - в 1.9 нет хэндлера toggle а вам просто click подойдет, т.к. функции одинаковые http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4wkRD/